# if i delete product in woocommerce, does it stay in trash forever or is it deleted permantly automatically in 30 days

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If I delete a product in woocommerce, does it stay in trash forever or is it deleted permantly automatically in 30 days?

I want to be able to make invisible certain products, but when I select "hidden" from catalog search they remain visible, so I need to put them into trash.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the status to `Pending` or `Draft`.